# DB2 Entity Framework Transaction Isolation "WITH UR"

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, db2

I am trying to make use of "**WITH UR**" in every query that goes to db2. does anybody know how to use transaction isolation in db2 ef4? i want linq to create me a following query:

**SELECT EmployeeID FROM Payroll.Employees WITH UR;**

Note: I already tried using `TransactionScope` provided in the .net framework 4.0; it doesn't help at all.

Comment: If your provider doesn't offer this setting through some explicit configuration, you will not be able to achieve that on generic level without writing your own EF provider for DB2.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the exact same question and haven't gotten anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that sDB2ConnectionString is the string you use to connect to DB2.

The isolation level is specified on the Transaction, but the Transaction.IsolationLevel property is readonly. You can only set it when you create the transaction.

For simplicity I have used a call to a stored procedure with no parameters. You can, of course, put any kind of DB2Command within the scope of the transaction.

```
// string sDB2ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[environment + "_ConnectionString"];

using ( DB2Connection conn = new DB2Connection( sDB2ConnectionString ) )
{
    conn.Open();

    using ( DB2Transaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction( IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted ) )
    {
        using ( DB2Command dbCommand = conn.CreateCommand() )
        {
            dbCommand.Transaction = tran;
            dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            dbCommand.CommandText = "MySchema.MyStoredProcedureName";

            dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            tran.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```